# How can I convert mmm-dd to SQL Server datetime?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I was trying to insert data from a `nvarchar(6)` column into a `datetime` column from one table to another using insert from select.

Here is the query I am working on:

```
INSERT INTO WORKORDERS ([A-POWDER BY], [A-MOUNT BY])
     SELECT  
         [A-POWDER BY], [A-MOUNT BY]
     FROM  
         [table 1]
```

This is some sample data:

```
 id   [A-POWDER BY]  [A-MOUNT BY]
 ---------------------------------
  1        Aug-16      Aug-16   
  2        Aug-26      Aug-27   
  3        Aug-15      Aug-16   
  4        Dec-16      Dec-16   
  5        Apr-16      Apr-16   
  6        Oct-16      Oct-16
```

and this is the error I get:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

The data format looks like `Aug-16`. I tried using `CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [datefield], 105) AS datetime` but I still get the same error.

How can I fix it?.

Thank you

Comment: Can you show us the query and some sample data?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i added the query

Comment: The date `Aug-16` looks problematical to me because there is no day present and we can't use `CONVERT()` without a date AFAIK.

Comment: Update your question and show us sample date strings.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen added sample date string

Comment: So what are you expecting the datetime to be? 1st of those months?

Comment: @MartinSmith want the same because some date are from 2016 also there are some from 2017 so i like to keep the same format but instead `Aug-16` preferred to be `Aug 16` or \no hyphen

Comment: What is "want the same"? Are you missing the year completely from your data, or what is that 26 and 27 there?

Comment: Yes i get the data in excel format some of the date were to `42865` and i convert them in excel date-format. 26 and 27 are the date

Answer (score 0):

I don't think trying to insert a date string of the form `Aug-16` will work because there is no day specified.  If you would be OK using the first of the month, then you can build a date string using concatenation and then convert it to a bona fide datetime.

```
INSERT INTO WORKORDERS (
    [A-POWDER BY],
    [A-MOUNT BY]
)
SELECT  
    CONVERT(datetime,
            '01 ' + LEFT([A-POWDER BY], 3) + ' ' + RIGHT([A-POWDER BY], 2),
            6),      -- 6 format mask for 'dd mon yy'
    CONVERT(datetime,
            '01 ' + LEFT([A-MOUNT BY], 3) + ' ' + RIGHT([A-MOUNT BY], 2),
            6)
FROM [table 1]
```

Comment: Tim Why does all 2000 records month set to 1?

Comment: sorry i want rather `month date` The month and the year part are correct but sets `1` for the date  as `9/1/2017, 5/1/2016` as mm dd yyyy :)

Comment: A datetime has a day, month, and year component.  It doesn't make sense to speak of a datetime without a day.

Answer (score 0):

You can use convert along with '01-' as below:

```
INSERT INTO WORKORDERS ([A-POWDER BY], [A-MOUNT BY])
     SELECT  
         [A-POWDER BY]= (convert(date, '01-',[A-POWDER BY])) , [A-MOUNT BY]= (convert(date, '01-',[A-MOUNT BY]))
     FROM  [table 1]
```